# Atom Editor theme change the color of curly brackets when Cursor is Positioned at either start or end

Tags: atom-editor

By default the Atom editor highlights the opening and closing curly brackets by a dotted undeline which is hard to see. I want this highlighting to be more obvious by changing this highlight to set a background color to the opening and closing curly brackets. How can I do that?  (I am working on a .js file if relevat)

I have searched google and found some links but nothing addresses this issue specifically. I have searched the atom editor documentation too to no avail.

I found the styles.less file where this can be done but have no clue how to target this character to style it.

```
//Example
// style the background and foreground colors on the atom-text-editor-element itself
//This is a made up name for targeting character:
atom-text-editor-curly-brackets {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

I want to be able to find the opening or closing curly bracket at a quick glance when I position my cursor on either end by highlighting the curly bracket character with a color background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked this discussion out?
https://discuss.atom.io/t/set-colour-of-bracket-and-matched-bracket/39018/2

> The selector for that is:
>
> `.bracket-matcher .region {
>         // your styles here
>      }`
>
> Add it to your user stylesheet (.atom/styles.less).

seems like you won't be able to easily style the brackets themselves (make them green etc) but setting a colorful background behind them seems possible
!